# QUERY String to php array and log to file

Tags: php, arrays

Im trying to work out how best to grab the QUERY string data and place that into an array. THen id like to log that array data to a txt file.

So far im going down this route;

```
$string = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];

parse_str($string, $output);
echo $output['first'];
echo $output['arr'][0];
echo $output['arr'][1];
echo $output['arr'][2];
echo $output['arr'][3];
echo $output['arr'][4];

fputs($log, $output);
```

Im able to write REFERER, HOST, METHOD etc to the file fine but the array doesnt work :(, any pointers?

Ive only added the parts relating to the array and log write of the array (as you can see)

Comment: What do you mean "doesn't work"? Specify your results

Comment: the results is a blank entry for $output

Comment: @AlmaDo guessing im doing something wrong, does the above look correct for parse_str?

Comment: Because you're trying to write array as string. Use something like `fputs($log, join(';', $output));` - but for multi-dimentional array you'll have to create stringifier manually

Comment: Example works fine: http://codepad.org/LnEvCJJ6 check your query string

Comment: @AlmaDo ill give it ago, but how does adding ; fix it?

Comment: i now get an entry that says Array in the file. lol what can i use instead of `parse_str($string, $output);` to parse the QUERY string into an array?

Comment: @jk. yeah I can see it works if your using a string but looks its as @AlmaDo said. the `$string = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];` isnt a string?

Comment: Can't you just use `$_GET` for this?

Comment: @RocketHazmat not sure how would that work? how would i place that into an array?

Comment: @LearningCode: `$_GET` *is* an array.  When you go to a URL with a query string `page.php?a=b&c=d`, `$_GET` is auto-built as an array.  Try to `var_dump($_GET);`.

Comment: @RocketHazmat thanks for explaining, ill use that :)

Comment: @RocketHazmat want to suggest an answer so i can select it as ermm the ANSWER lol?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP will (usually) automatically parse the query string into the `$_GET` array for you.

See: http://php.net/get